# Python returns an element of sublist if the given element present in that sublist

Tags: python, list, indexing

How to make the python returns this:

```
list = [['a', 23, 'h401'], ['f', 45, 'h403'], ['g', 56, 'h401']]
```

If `'h401'` is given as an input, it should return the total of numbers in the index of `[1]` of sublists with `'h401'`

```
>>> 79                 #(23 + 56)
```

same as if `'h403`' is given it should return the `[1]` of sublist with `'h403'` which is `45`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inp = input("input code")
mlist = [['a', 23, 'h401'], ['f', 45, 'h403'], ['g', 56, 'h401']]
count = 0
for i in range (len(mlist)):
    if (mlist[i][2] == inp):
        count += mlist[i][1]

print(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an expression to select the second element only if your third element is `h401` and sum them.

```
l = [['a', 23, 'h401'], ['f', 45, 'h403'], ['g', 56, 'h401']]

sum(i[1] for i in l if i[2] == 'h401')
```

If you just want to check for your target element to be in the list, you can use:

```
sum(i[1] for i in l if 'h401' in i)
```

Comment: If 'h401' could be in some other index than 2, you can use `'h401' in i` instead of `i[2] == 'h401'`. It's not really clear from the question whether it's always in the same index.

Comment: Thanks @HåkenLid. Edited the answer to include any element in list.